# Setting up Mongo DB and hosting

Tags: hosting, couchdb, mongodb

Recently I stumbled across mongoDB, couchDB etc. 
I am hoping to have a play with this type of database and was wondering how much access to the hosting server one needs to get it running.

If anyone has any knowledge of this, I would love to know whether it can be set up to work when your app is hosted via a 'normal' hosting company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Mongo, and so I'm really only speaking for Mongo, but your typical web hosting environment wouldn't allow you to set up your own database.  You'd want root-level (admin) access to the server to set up Mongo.  To get that, you'd want something like a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) or a dedicated server.

However, to just play around with Mongo, I'd recommend downloading the binary for your OS and giving it a run.  Their JavaScript shell interface is very easy to use.

Hope that helps!
Tim

Answer (score 2):

Various ways:-

1) There are many free mongodb hosting available. Try DotCloud.com. Many others here http://www.cloudhostingguru.com/mongoDB-server-hosting.php

2) If you are asking specifically about shared hosting, the answer is mostly no. But, if you could run mongoDB somewhere else (like from the above link) and want to connect from your website, it is probably possible if your host allows your own extensions (for php)

3) VPS

Answer (score 1):

How about [virtual private server hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server)?  The host gives you what looks like an entire machine... hard drive, CPU, memory.  You get to install whatever you want, since it's your (virtual) machine.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of MongoDB like others have said, you need the ability to install the MongoDB software and run it (normally as a daemon). However, hosted services are just beginning to appear, such as [MongoHQ](https://app.mongohq.com/home). Perhaps something like this might be appropriate once its out of beta (or if you request an invite).

It appears hosted CouchDB services are also popping up, such as [couch.io](http://hosting.couch.io/) or [Cloudant](http://cloudant.com/). I personally have no experience with Couch so I can be less certain than with Mongo, but I'd imagine that again to run it yourself, you'd need to install the software (and thus require root access).

If you don't currently have a VPS or dedicated server (or the cloud-based versions of the aforementioned), perhaps moving your data out to a dedicated hosted service would be an ideal way to go to avoid the pain and expense of changing your hosting setup.

Comment: actually, Cloudant doesn't just host CouchDB, they have bunch of awesome additions to CouchDB that they use for auto-sharding. They are an awesome storage provider if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your application and your database in the different hosting servers. 
For MongoDB you can use [mongohq](https://www.mongohq.com/) or [mongolab](https://mongolab.com) with space 0.5 Gb for free